# Insert digital signature field into dynamically-created PDF

Tags: pdf, coldfusion

I'm trying to dynamically create a PDF, of which a user can control by editing the templated text of and then download it from the browser. The templated text is controlled through storing a CLOB in the database. That's all fine and easy, but I also need to add a digital/electronic signature field at the bottom of the generated PDF. I've found little documentation on this, but it seems the ColdFusion way of doing this is to use a `cfpdf action="sign"`, with the documentation giving this as an example:

```
<cfpdf action="sign"
source="#inputfilepath##inputfilename#"
destination="#signedfilepath##signedfilename#"
keystore="#certpath#cert.pfx" keystorepassword="certpass"
overwrite="true" pages="1" height="100"
width="100" position="100,100" author="false"
/>
```

The file path to the ColdFusion server's keystore is "C:/Program Files/jdk-11.0.10/lib/security/cacerts/". There appears to be no cert file in there. Would one need generated by using `keytool` in the command line, as referenced [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html)?

My second option (after `cfpdf`) seems to be implementing the `iText` library through `cfscript`, since ColdFusion is Java-driven and runs on a JVM. Here is a mockup I was able to create that might result in something I'm looking for:

```
<cfscript>
    resource = CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream");
    resource.init("C:\path\OriginalLetter.pdf");
    os = CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream");
    os.init("C:\path\NewLetter.pdf");
    annotation = CreateObject("java", "com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation");
    annotation.init();
    reader = CreateObject("java", "com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader");
    reader.init(resource);
    stamper = CreateObject("java", "com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper");
    stamper.init(reader, os);
    FormField = CreateObject("java", "com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFormField");
    FormField.init();
    field = FormField.createSignature(stamper.getWriter());
    field.setFieldName("Signature");
    field.setWidget(new Rectangle(30, 830, 170, 770), annotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
    stamper.addAnnotation(field, 1);
    stamper.close();
</cfscript>
```

But there seems to be uncertainty if such an implementation would be functional on ColdFusion's side.

Again, there seems to be little I can find on this and could use some guidance from people experienced in ColdFusion administration or even in a problem similar to this. My backup plan is to put the actual template PDF file - which already has the signature block at the bottom - on the server file system and then the user can simply edit the text within from there, and the signature field would stay at the bottom. To explain this better, the templated text I use from the DB is based off the contents of this file; it's just I can't store something like a PDF digital signature field as text. More specifically, I am using HTML to generate the content so it can be formatted better. The user can edit the text through a `ckeditor` on the browser, but again, a simple `input` would not render as a signature field on a PDF.

Comment: Maybe it's lack of coffee, but not sure I follow :) The first part sounds like you're trying to add an *empty* signature field to a pdf (that would eliminate cfpdf action=sign as a solution since the action applies a signature to a field that already exists in the pdf) But later you say "..already has the signature block at the bottom... keeping the signature field", suggesting the pdf already contains the signature field. I don't have an answer for you, but perhaps clarifying might help someone else provide some direction.

Comment: @SOS You're correct that I'm trying to add an empty signature field. The `cfpdf action="sign"` in the example from the docs I gave had a comment above it, saying "Sign a specific pdf by creating a signature field and signing it with authored signature." So it seems it does both create and sign the signature field, even though I'm only interested in creation. The actual PDF file I'm referencing has a signature field in it, but I'm generating this PDF with templated text from a database, and then the user can edit it. My last resort was using the file instead of DB to have the signature field.

Comment: @SOS If that doesn't explain it, see my edited question, specifically the last paragraph.

Comment: (Edit) Yeah, I'm not sure if it does both, but if you need an empty signature field, the fact that the action also signs the field make that a non-starter. Is this pdf static or a fillable pdf form?

Comment: In other words, is the "template pdf" you mentioned a fillable pdf form...?

Comment: @SOS This is a static form. Just a letter with text that is meant to be sent to another person, although there is the signature field you would fill, in addition to a couple checkboxes and a date field.

Comment: @max-voisard I have some example web apps where I have solved in several ways that you can use for reference. 1) do you need the ability for the users to apply a signature on the web? 2) or, you wish to relay on the pdf signature Feild? If so how does your app plan on storing the signed document. 

Contact me we can look at some of my reference examples

Comment: @Peter Thanks for reaching out. If I had to pick between the two, I would want the ability for users to apply a signature on the Web, as that is always a bonus. For your examples, feel free to post the one you think should be the answer, but if you want to discuss which I need, you can call me at (937)-638-4972 or email me at max.voisard@gmail.com. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a solution already, but you are able to add formfields using the Adobe Sign API. I mention it because you are looking to have people sign the document.

I haven't used it myself ( yet ), but I too need to do the same after creating a pdf with Coldfusion's CFDOCUMENT.

[Adobe Acrobat Sign API - FAQ](https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/faq/api.html)

There is a monetary cost with using the API however, but perhaps the workflow of collecting signatures may suit you.